# A question about Linear transformations on matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

We know that if $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation, then there exists a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $T(x)=Ax$, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, if $T:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a linear transformation,, similarly, does there exist a matrix like $C$ such that
$$T(A)=CA,$$ 
for every $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Comment: For a particular example following apfel's answer, let $T$ be the transpose map on $n \times n$ matrices.  This is a linear transformation, but you can't get the transpose just by multiplying by a fixed $n \times n$ matrix.  So there are more linear maps than those induced by simple matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is not possible in the form you suggested.

However, you can vectorize $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ by stacking its columns on top of each other which gives a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$, say $a$, and then represent any linear map $a\mapsto b$ as matrix multiplication $b=Ca$ where $C\in\mathbb{R}^{mn\times mn}$. The key is that each element of $b$ is a linear combination of *all* the elements of $a$. Then you can form a matrix $B$ out of the vector $b$. Any linear map from $A\mapsto B$ can be obtained in this way.

In the original form that you suggested $B=CA$, each element of $B$ would not have been a linear combination of all the elements of $A$. For example, $B_{1,1}$ is a linear combination only of the first column of $A$ but none of the others. Then, the coefficients are of course given by the first row of $C$.